# Leaflet - Creating lines to connect GeoJSON points

Tags: leaflet, geojson, data, point

How do I create lines connecting GeoJSON point features with the same "ligne" data following a given order (Id for exemple).

This is what my GeoJSON looks like :

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "test",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 0, "nom": "JAMAA EL FNA", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -7.991506070410076, 31.624380871588261 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1, "nom": "KOUTOUBIA", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -7.993921192850516, 31.62551706188404 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 2, "nom": "HOTE DE VILLE", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -7.997800602958748, 31.627492814514493 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 3, "nom": "R.P BERDII", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -8.003733858117105, 31.630010280990067 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 4, "nom": "GRAND POSTE", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -8.009040991276375, 31.633004916540266 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 5, "nom": "CAREE EDEN", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -8.011327830139466, 31.634311225216251 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 6, "nom": "PL ABDELMOUMEN", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -8.01491129321975, 31.63631744889955 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 7, "nom": "PLACE D ARMES", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -8.017961238223567, 31.63862644522986 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 8, "nom": "FST", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -8.019317263334594, 31.64420691382918 ] } }, .....
```

Comment: What GIS tool / programming language / library are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Leaflet

Comment: you will have to make a loop through your geojson features and recreate a linestring. in StackExchange you have to show what you have tried so far like code example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you wanna find shortest path on google or other maps you can use a for loop and google maps api. i wrote a simple code for you. [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/gislayer/pen/KBwMKd?editors=0010)